# Data types between PostgreSQL and Golang

Tags: postgresql, go, pq

```
type User struct {
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    Password  string `json:"password"`
}

db, err := sql.Open("postgres", os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("email: ", reflect.TypeOf(usr.Email)) //string
    fmt.Println("salt: ", reflect.TypeOf(salt))       //[]uint8
    fmt.Println("hash: ", reflect.TypeOf(hash))       //string

    sql := `INSERT INTO public."Users" (email, password, salt) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`

    _, err = db.Exec(sql, usr.Email, hash, salt)
```

throws error: "pq: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x97"
my table:  "email" type: TEXT,  "password" type: TEXT,  "salt" type: smallint[] (thinking this might be the cause of the error but I am not sure what to use instead)

Comment: Maybe `salt` column is a string? Try `string(salt)`

Comment: salt column is smallint[], I can't transform the whole array or it will be a high cost when it comes time to transform and use the []uint8 to login.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL bytea = []unit8 Golang

changed type and issue was resolved!